# Water Tight Templates?

Tags: mixing, pro-tools, editing, workflow, templates

Sup peps,

Just wanted to discuss the use to templates in an everyday workflow and the pros and cons of working in such a manor...

I have recently discovered that its very easy (not to mention fun) building a template for say 5.1 dialogue editing/mixing.. But once I started it, I got sucked into trying to make it water tight so it could be "The Last Template I Would Ever Need". Like a Swiss army template. However it struck me that of course its an unachievable task as every project will be different with different needs and specifications... so how deep do you guys make your templates before you step back and say "this will do!"? Does anyone feel like they have a water tight template or do you prefer to just build your sessions from the scratch? Tem

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I have a folder containing all of my templates. They're often updated as I discover more efficient ways of doing things. My workflow is a constant evolution, so water doesn't work for me.

If for example I have a Mix_Surround template and need to do a stereo mix, I simply duplicate it, adapt it to a stereo mix and save at as Mix_Stereo. I'm now ready to work and have a new template ready for the next time.

There is no harm in having 5,10 + specific templates. In the long run you save yourself time. As your workflow changes and you discover tricks you'll want to incorporate them.

Happy templating!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Templates is the only way I work - ensures efficiency and reliability.  I honestly can't begin to think of not working with them, especially for large feature film layouts.  I have various templates (DX, ADR, Foley, FX, BGz, Sub/Stem/PM layouts, etc), and some templates from studios I've worked with where the mixer has provided what they like to use and expect to see in a stage delivery - so on shows with those studios, I use their provided templates.  When I crew up with other people on a show I'm supervising, I give out a template to my editors which I'd like for them to use on the show.  Usually all these templates are just tracks, coloring, and naming - in some template cases, additionally bussing and and aux assignments are part of it.  Everything else though remains blank.  For plugins, I just know my go-to's and have made presets of them for certain things so I can quickly build a signal chain on the fly and tweak from there.

You're right, every scenario is different.  Yet in my experience, I've found the variety to be not very much (at least for doing post sound), and in many cases you can easily conform a shows needs to fit within one of a few templates.

On some cases I'll tweak a copy of the layout I make to use for a show, because you may have a show where for instance your BG layout it fine, but there's so much water/beach in the film, it's nice to have a dedicated 8 tracks for waves (versus water/ocean tones).  In these kinds of cases, I make a tweak o the layout only for the specific show in question.  But I always begin from a set of core templates and extrapolate from there if and when necessary - usually everything fits within the original template construct in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I was talking to a studio owner friend a few weeks back and he said they'd been tweaking their 5.1 template for four months and it still wasn't just right. I'm still tweaking my templates as well. So don't beat yourself up too much.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that I have seen One Template to Rule Them All be even remotely feasible is at an on-lot facility where every channel has the same QC requirements. Even in that instance, the mega-template that took the most complicated mix into account was overkill for at least 60% of the daily projects and took forever to load.

The beauty of templates is that you can have an array of basic templates that offer you a good starting point depending on the type of job, and then customize them for the scope, delivery requirements, etc.